# Passing Scripts as Arguments Bash

Tags: bash

This script is incomplete since I will want to do error testing later, but the idea is that ARG is a script and ARG2 is a directory, and ARG should mark all of the files in ARG2. How would I do this in such a way that bash knows the first argument has to be a script and argument 2 is a directory?

```
ARG=$1
ARG2=$2
CHECK=0
aCount=0
bCount=0
cCount=0
dCount=0
fCount=0

if [ $CHECK -e 0 ]; then
    for files in $ARG2; do
        if [ sh $1 $2 -eq A]; then
            aCount=$((aCount+1))
        elif [ sh $1 $2 -eq B]; 
            bCount=$((bCount+1))
        elif [ sh $1 $2 -eq C]; 
            cCount=$((cCount+1))
        elif [ sh $1 $2 -eq D ];
            dCount=$((dCount+1))
        else;
            fCount=$((fCount+1))
        fi
    done
fi

echo A: $aCount
echo B: $bCount       
echo C: $cCount          
echo D: $dCount
echo F: $fCount
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a variety of errors you could catch by running your script through **[shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net/)**.

**Corrections:**

- To loop over the files in a directory, write `for file in dir/*` not `for file in dir`. The latter just loops once with `$file` set to the string `"dir"`, rather than iterating over the contents of the directory `dir/`.
- `[ sh $1 $2 -eq A]` is a jumble of shell constructs. You want to capture the output of the script, so you need `$(...)`. You're doing a string check, so you should use `==` not `-eq`. Correcting both yields:

  ```
  [ $(sh $1 $2) == A ]
  ```
- I'm guessing `$2` should be `$files`, though. The loop variable, yes?

  ```
  [ $(sh $1 $files) == A ]
  ```
- There are other miscellaneous mistakes, such as missing `then`s and not always having a space before `]`.

**Improvements:**

- You should quote everything properly to prevent inadvertent word splitting and glob expansion.

  ```
  [ "$(sh "$1" "$files")" == A ]
  ```
- Let's replace `$1` with `$script` and `$files` with singular `$file`.

  ```
  [ "$(sh "$script" "$file")" == A ]
  ```
- If the script has a proper shebang line like `#!/bin/bash` at the top then there's no need to explicitly invoke `sh`.

  ```
  [ "$("$script" "$file")" == A ]
  ```
- That's all great. Now you have something like this:

  ```
  if [ "$("$script" "$file")" == A ]; then
      aCount=$((aCount+1))
  elif [ "$("$script" "$file")" == B ]; then
      bCount=$((bCount+1))
  elif [ "$("$script" "$file")" == C ]; then
      cCount=$((cCount+1))
  elif [ "$("$script" "$file")" == D ]; then
      dCount=$((dCount+1))
  else
      fCount=$((fCount+1))
  fi
  ```

  Awfully repetitious, no? Let's try a `case` statement instead.

  ```
  case "$("$script" "$file")" in
      A) aCount=$((aCount+1));;
      B) bCount=$((bCount+1));;
      C) cCount=$((cCount+1));;
      D) dCount=$((dCount+1));;
      *) fCount=$((fCount+1));;
  esac
  ```
- That case statement is still quite complex. Let's break it up to make it easier to parse.

  ```
  grade=$("$script" "$file")

  case $grade in
      ...
  esac
  ```
- Variable names ought to be lowercase. UPPERCASE names are reserved for the shell, so best not to use those. Change `COUNT` to `count`.
- Let's rename `ARG` and `ARG2` to `script` and `dir`, respectively. Meaningful names make everything easier to read.
- `var=$((var+1))` can be simplified to `((var += 1))` or `((var++))`.

**End result:**

```
script=$1
dir=$2

check=0
aCount=0
bCount=0
cCount=0
dCount=0
fCount=0

if ((check == 0)); then
    for file in "$dir"/*; do
        grade=$("$script" "$file")

        case $grade in
            A) ((aCount++));;
            B) ((bCount++));;
            C) ((cCount++));;
            D) ((dCount++));;
            *) ((fCount++));;
        esac
    done
fi

echo "A: $aCount"
echo "B: $bCount"
echo "C: $cCount"
echo "D: $dCount"
echo "F: $fCount"
```

Answer (score 2):

@[John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman) did a *great* job above. For an alternate take -

```
declare -A count                   # count is an array
for file in "$dir"/*               # skipping assignments, and $check
do grade=$("$script" "$file")      # grab the output as $grade
   case $grade in                  # look up its value
   [A-D]) (( count[$grade]++ ));;  # use as-is for a-d
       *) (( count['F']++    ));;  # throw everything else in f
   esac
done

for g in A B C D F                 # then for a-f (known values)
do echo "$g: "${count[$g]}         # pull the counts
done
```

Comment: An array is a great idea. I ran out of space in my answer. ;)

Comment: You'll want `declare -A` for an associative array.

Comment: I *had* `-A`, and started testing a couple options, and ended up not putting it back. Thanks, edited/corrected.